# Jython/Python Name not found globally

Tags: python, jython

Please help me, I got this error:

```
diagonal Name not found globally.
A local or global name could not be found. You need to define the function or variable before you try to use it in any way.
```

Could you also help with how I can use `print.now()` and display the three variables.
Thanks

```
 def computeSquareFeatures(p):

  p = input("Enter square side length:")
  area = p*p
  perimeter = p*4
  diagonal = math.sqrt(2*(p**2))

  print.Now("Area is %d, Perimeter is %d, Diagonal length is %d") % area, perimeter, diagonal

computeSquareFeatures(p)
```

Comment: Where does `print.Now` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in `p` but not declaring it before you do:

```
computeSquareFeatures(p)
```

You set `p` using `input` inside the function.

You also need to make `p`an int inside the function or your area calculation won't do what your think, make sure you have imported math and the `print.Now` does not seem correct either.

An example of a working function:

```
import math
# removed p as you are taking getting it as input
def computeSquareFeatures():
  p = int(raw_input("Enter square side length: "))
  area = p*p
  perimeter = p*4
  diagonal = math.sqrt(2*(p**2))
  print("Area is %d, Perimeter is %d, Diagonal length is %d") %(area, perimeter, diagonal)

computeSquareFeatures()
```

It works as seen below:

```
$jython jt.py
Enter square side length:33
Area is 1089, Perimeter is 132, Diagonal length is 46
```

Comment: how would i declare as a int

Comment: just `computeSquareFeatures(123)` but bare in mind you are overwriting as soon as you take input

Comment: what do u mean by 123

Comment: I mean pass any number you like, it makes no difference as you reassign `p` inside anyway

Comment: can u please put it where it would go in my code, sorry i just started the language

Comment: @JaskiratGrover, I added an example

Comment: Inappropriate argument value (of correct type). error on line 4

Comment: Invalid syntax
Your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal jython.
Look at line 4 of the current file.
That line refers to the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\JES 4.3\Sources\media.py'.
The file 'media.py' has a syntax error on line 967.

Comment: i get `Area is 16, Perimeter is 16, Diagonal length is 5`

Comment: you can see my output, how are you running it?

Comment: when i enter my side length, nothing is printed

Comment: Enter square side length: 33
>>> print area
25
>>> print "%d" % area
25
>>>

Comment: i am getting 25 for my are for some reason where as length is 33